# Error when trying to load bitmaps

Tags: android

Why do I get the error message `The method getResources() is undefined for the type ColorObjectManager`?

I use this line to load a Bitmap image:

```
orange = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pearl_orange);
```

It's working fine if I'm doing this in another class that I call `GameLoop` which I make an object of inside the `MainActivity` class. But it's not working when I trying to do this in the class `ColorObjectManager` which I make an object of inside the `GameLoop` class. Do you follow?

Why am I limited to just use this loading part in the `GameLoop` class and not in the `ColorObjectManager` class? I thought it would help if I passed the Context to the constructor of `ColorObjectManager`, but it didn't! I guess I'm missing some knowledge here where I can create objects and not. Can I get some help to sort this out? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will need to call `context.getResources()`.

Comment: Context mContext;
         public ColorObjectManager(Context context)
         {
              this.mContext= context;
         } Pass the context to the constructor and use the same.

Comment: @Raghunandan Do I really need to use the Context mContext and then later this.mContext = context !? It's working if I'm just using the context parameter and pass it to an method that loads the images. And I thought I only needed to use 'this' if I hade the same name like Context context in the beginning of the class and then in constructor this.context = context. Please explain if you have time!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ when you receive the context in the constructor you can pass the context to the method that loads the images. this refers to the current context. Is your ColorObjectManger a non activity class?. You mean to say in your constructor you would call load(context). is that what you meant?

Comment: if you need only inside that method add the Context as paramter

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes I guess my class ColorObjectManger is a non activity class, because it's not in the manifest file!? Am I thinking right? In my constructor of ColorObjectManger class I just do Like this: ColorObjectManger(Context context) { loadTexture(context); } I'm not using Context context in the beginning of the class. It's working, but is it bad or OK programming?

Comment: check the edit section in my answer. see the comment by @blackbelt above.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes I did. I guess if I'm using Context context in the beginning of class, then context will be 'global' and I can use it at several places in the class, right?

Comment: @3D-kreativ if tonight somebody has not changed the "class field" meaning, I will answer yes You can

Comment: @Raghunandan OK! I do forget some basic things sometimes when I'm not doing this all the time. But I'm still wonder if 'this' really is necessary like you write this.mContext? I thought I would need to use 'this' only of the reference in the beginning of the class and the in parameter was the same like context and then in the constructor write this.context?! Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: @3D-kreativ pls check the link for clarity http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResource` needs a Context object. If you pass the `context`  to `ColorObjectManager` you can retrieve resources with `context.getResources()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! You were the first to answer!

Comment: you are welcome (probably you want write "You were not where" :D )

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer posted by blackbelt. Pass the activity context to the constructor of ColorObjectManager from your activity class.

```
     new ColorObjectManger(ActivityName.this);
```

Constructor

```
     Context mContext;
     public ColorObjectManager(Context context)
     {
          this.mContext= context;
     }
```

Then use the context to get resources.

Edit:

If you want to use the context only in your load method

```
     public ColorObjectManager(Context context)
     {
          load(context);
     }
```

Comment: Please see my comment above!

Answer (score 0):

To get access getResources() , Activity context is required. Your **ColorObjectManager** is not an Activity. So you need to pass the Activity context to this class.